# Hide form fields unless 'add node image (etc) link is clicked

Tags: theming

I have content type with many fields. I'd like to simplify the form as best I can and hide un-needed text boxes/checkboxes/options whenever possible. Is there a module you know of which will replace an entire field with an 'add this field' hyperlink. When clicked that field would obviously become visible.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module. It's still in -dev state for D7 but maybe it works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I use css to hide fields in my edit forms. You can add some custom css that will "unhide" certain fields when a link is clicked.

The [css_injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) module is great to inject css on certain pages.

Comment: and some JS yeah?!